# Regex to get language matches

Tags: regex

I have the following input:

```
_YUE_ENSUB_L9939486_16X9
```

And I would like to match on `YUE` and `EN`. The conditions are:

- Between two `_`, it only allows `[A-Z419]`.
- It should not include the suffix `SUB`, `SUBS`, or `FN`.

So far I have:

```
([A-Z419]+)(?:SUB|FN|SUBS)?
```

Or:

```
[A-Z419]{2,5}(?=SUB)
```

But both fall a bit short. What would be the correct regex for this? I suppose something like this perhaps but it seems a bit overkill and probably not a great match:

```
[A-Z419]+(?=SUB|FN|SUBS)|[A-Z419]+(?!=SUB|FN|SUBS)
```

Here are sample inputs from [`regex101`](https://regex101.com/r/Y6gxay/4).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Search for:

```
^_([^_]*)_([^_]*)(SUB|SUBS|FN)
```

You have the languages in capture groups 1 and 2.

Test [**here**](https://regex101.com/r/H3D1cl/1).

---

For the updated question:

Regex:

```
_([A-Z419]*?)(SUB|SUBS|FN)?(?=_)
```

Languages are in capture group 1.

Test [**here**](https://regex101.com/r/H3D1cl/2).

Comment: I've updated the inputs in the question. Here is a link: https://regex101.com/r/Y6gxay/2.

Comment: great, that works. I'd adjust it just a tiny bit to make the SUB part not capturing: `(?<=_)([A-Z419]+?)(?:SUB|SUBS|FN)?(?=_)`

Answer (score 2):

You might use a capturing group and move the lookahead to right after the first underscore. Then match either SUB with an optional S or FN and an underscore.

```
_(?![A-Z419]*(?:SUBS?|FN)_)([A-Z419]+)_
```

**Explanation**

- `_` Match literally
- `(?!` Negative lookahead, assert what is on the right does not match

  - `[A-Z419]*` Match 0+ times any of the listed chars
  - `(?:SUBS?|FN)_` Match either SUB, SUBS or FN followed by `_`
- `)` Close lookahead
- `(` Capture **group 1**

  - `[A-Z419]+` Match 1+ times any of the listed chars
- `)_` Close group and match an underscore

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/xOIAhg/1)

For the updated question, you could get the matches only:

```
(?<=_)[A-Z419]+?(?=(?:SUBS?|FN)?_)
```

**Explanation**

- `(?<=_)` Positive lookbehind, assert what is directly to the left is `_`
- `[A-Z419]+?` Match one of the listed char, as least as possible
- `(?=` Positive lookahead, assert what is directly to the right

  - `(?:SUBS?|FN)?_` Optionally match SUB, SUBS or FN followed by `_`
- `)` Close lookahead

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/b1FRMo/1)

Comment: OK, but it seems to be missing some of the language matches. The one that works best for me is something like: `(?<=_)([A-Z419]+?)(?:SUB|SUBS|FN)?(?=_)`

Comment: Here is an update on what should be matched as well if that helps: https://regex101.com/r/Y6gxay/4.

Comment: @carl.hiass I have added a pattern to get the matches only.